# How can i use angular-calendar in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular17

I'm converting Angular 9 project into Angular 17 and one component got angular-calendar plugin which was last published an year ago,

in component.html it's implemented like this,

```
    <mwl-calendar-month-view
      *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
      (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
      (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
      (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)">
    </mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

in the component.ts i have imported the modules like following,

```
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxDropzoneModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }),
  ],
```

but still the component didn't get recognized, in component.html. getting errros like this,

```
NG8002: Can't bind to 'refresh' since it isn't a known property of 'mwl-calendar-day-view'.
1. If 'mwl-calendar-day-view' is an Angular component and it has 'refresh' input, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'mwl-calendar-day-view' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component. [plugin angular-compiler]
```

any idea how to resolve this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for angular standalone component, we need to import `CalendarModule` to the imports array of the standalone component, also ensure that we add the environment providers using `importProvidersFrom` so that the providers are available in the application

full code

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import {
  CalendarEvent,
  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,
  CalendarWeekViewBeforeRenderEvent,
  CalendarDayViewBeforeRenderEvent,
  CalendarModule,
  DateAdapter,
} from 'angular-calendar';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';

export const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3',
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF',
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CalendarModule],
  template: `
    <mwl-calendar-month-view
      [viewDate]="viewDate"
      [events]="events"
      [activeDayIsOpen]="true"
      [refresh]="refresh"
      (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
    >
    </mwl-calendar-month-view>
  `,
})
export class App {
  view: string = 'week';
  snapDraggedEvents = true;

  dayStartHour = 6;
  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
      title: 'Draggable event',
      color: colors.yellow,
      start: new Date(),
      draggable: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'A non draggable event',
      color: colors.blue,
      start: new Date(),
    },
  ];

  refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  eventTimesChanged({ event, newStart, newEnd }: any): void {
    event.start = newStart;
    event.end = newEnd;
    this.refresh.next(null);
  }
  public segmentIsValid(date: Date) {
    // valid if time is greater than 0800 andd less than 1700
    return date.getHours() >= 8 && date.getHours() <= 17;
  }
  beforeDayViewRender(day: CalendarDayViewBeforeRenderEvent): void {
    // day.body.hourGrid.forEach((hour) => {
    //   hour.segments.forEach((segment) => {
    //     if (!this.segmentIsValid(segment.date)) {
    //       delete segment.cssClass;
    //       segment.cssClass = 'cal-disabled';
    //     }
    //   });
    // });
  }
  beforeWeekViewRender(body: CalendarWeekViewBeforeRenderEvent): void {
    body.hourColumns.forEach((hourCol) => {
      hourCol.hours.forEach((hour) => {
        hour.segments.forEach((segment) => {
          if (!this.segmentIsValid(segment.date)) {
            delete segment.cssClass;
            segment.cssClass = 'cal-disabled';
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom(
      CalendarModule.forRoot({
        provide: DateAdapter,
        useFactory: adapterFactory,
      })
    ),
  ],
});
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zbf9lx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)